# Interconnection between two processes

Tags: python, sockets, unix-socket

I have two processes and I need to send messages between them. Here's the first file:

```
import socket
from info import socket1_filename, socket2_filename

socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
socket1.bind(socket1_filename)
socket2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
socket2.connect(socket2_filename)
```

And here's the second file:

```
import socket
from info import socket1_filename, socket2_filename

socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
socket1.connect(socket1_filename)
socket2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
socket2.bind(socket2_filename)
```

And here's the `info` module:

```
socket1_filename = '/tmp/socket1'
socket2_filename = '/tmp/socket2'
```

Of course this thing won't work, it's kind of a deadlock:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process1.py", line 7, in <module>
    socket2.connect(socket2_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So what is the way to implement simple interconnection between processes if I need to be able to send messages and receive them in both endpoints?

Comment: Perhaps catch the exception and retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tichodroma said, you'll need to retry.
Define a timeout (say, 10 seconds), and, while that time doesn't expire, catch `socket.error` and keep retrying. If it still fails after the timeout, fail loudly.

You'll need to `bind` before you attempt to `connect` on *both* processes, otherwise this will never succeed.

```
TIMEOUT= 10 #seconds
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep

timeout= datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=TIMEOUT)

socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
socket2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

socket2.bind(socket2_filename)

s1_done= False

while (not s1_done) and (datetime.now() < timeout):
    try:
        socket1.connect(socket1_filename)
        s1_done= True
    except socket.error:
        sleep(1)

if not s1_done:
    raise Exception("Failed to connect")
```

Comment: Yeah, it was very dumb question. Thank you guys!

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov don't forget to always `bind` first, connect after - otherwise it **will** be a deadlock. see the code I included